# How to track sales from multiple subdirectories, in Google Analytics, when they all share same checkout?

Tags: google-analytics, ecommerce

Is there an accurate way to track sales in Google Analytics when 3 different subdirectories share the same checkout URL?

We have a weird .Net setup where 3 different subdirectories of a subdomain are different stores, and are considered 3 separate websites.

Main subdomain is store.example.com.

Then each store is like this:

store.example.com/en-us/store1

store.example.com/en-us/store2

store.example.com/en-us/store3

**But they all share store.example.com/checkout**

I've created separate views for each store, but as you can imagine, on those views, I can't track sales because each view has a filter to only show traffic to that subdirectory. The store doesn't contain that subdirectory name, so sales are ignored.

So I created a rollup view with all 3 stores/subdirectories being tracked at once, in hopes that I could track sales. It is tracking sales fine, but now I'd like to segment out which subdirectory is responsible for what and how many sales.

How would you go about this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

**This method fails to break out purchases by store accurately because the checkout process is a separate subdirectory**

One way to do this is to create a **custom segment** using sequences. You may need to play around with the URL matching  a bit to get it right.

[image]

Once you get that set up, you should be able to filter the transactions down to only those sessions that follow that pattern. Repeat this for all your subdirectories.

**A more accurate way to do this is to change the site structure so that the checkout process is part of each store subdirectory:**

store.example.com/en-us/store1/checkout

store.example.com/en-us/store1/checkoutprocess

store.example.com/en-us/store2/checkout

store.example.com/en-us/store2/checkoutprocess

store.example.com/en-us/store3/checkout

store.example.com/en-us/store3/checkoutprocess

**Then set up a segment to capture each store's checkoutprocess URL.**

Comment: Oh, thank you for this! I'm experimenting with it now. It's not perfectly capturing all sales, but maybe I can play around with the URLs like you mentioned.

Comment: What are the exact URI's in your funnel?

Comment: /en-us/checkout  and then the final is /en-us/checkout/processcheckout/ with a dynamic code after the trailing slash of course. Interestingly I tried leaving off the trailing slash on "processcheckout" and it showed different, but even less transaction amounts.